# pd.read_json the table section of a json file

Tags: python, pandas

I have the a json file in the following format:

```
[
{"type":"header","version":"4.9.5deb2","comment":"Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin"},
{"type":"database","name":"restdb"},
{"type":"table","name":"RestApp_masterlist","database":"restdb","data":
[
    {"id":"1","Year":"2022"},
    {"id":"2","Year":"2022"} 
]
}
]
```

How can i use pd.read_json to return a dataframe that looks like:

```
id      Year
1       2022
2       2022
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: done, is that ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `pd.read_json()`. Read the JSON normally, then turn the `data:` list into the dataframe.

```
with open("file.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for item in data:
    if item['type'] == 'table':
        df = pd.Dataframe(item['data'])
        break
```

Comment: This worked thanks! Although just missing a `)` on 2nd last line